# React Native Android error in com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting an error caught by Crashlytics and it's happening to almost 45% of the users but it doesn't seem to happen when the user is using the app but when it's in the background.

The stacktrace shown on Crashlytics is:

`Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException ReadableNativeMap.java:124
lineNumber`

I have no clue what can be causing this issue, if it's a Javascript error or a native library error

Comment: Noticing the same exception since today. react-native: 0.56.0, react-native-fbsdk: 0.8.0

Comment: Same error on react-native 0.59.3, I believe some module should be blamed

Comment: Here is the bug report: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24382

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [problem caused](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24382#issuecomment-484381036) by the [stacktrace-parser](https://github.com/errwischt/stacktrace-parser/issues/10) library which is used internally by react native. Basically, release 0.1.4 works fine while releases 0.1.5 and 0.1.6 causes the lineNumber error.

Do the following to fix this:

1. If you are using **yarn** add the following to your package.json:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "stacktrace-parser": "0.1.4"
  },
```

if you are using **npm** add the following to your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "stacktrace-parser": "0.1.4"
```

2. Remove the yarn.lock (or package-lock.json) file and the node_modules directory.
3. Install the packages `yarn install` (or `npm install`)
4. Rebuild your release build.

I hope this helps others until the library gets fixed.

Comment: No, I have not tried with 0.1.8, but I am sure that they will solve the problem eventually. Once they do this answer will become obsolete. :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to remove every `console.error` in my project.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24382

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "backgroundColor" value is never null or undefined. In my case that was the reason.

Comment: Do you know anyway I can reproduce thismissue locally, because it seems to be happening when the app is in background?

Comment: In my case, the crash also happened when the app is in background

Answer (score -3):

It ended up being an issue with some native library that was causing the crash. Simply upgrading it solved the problem

Comment: which native library? you should have mention that.

Comment: This answer is not useful, you should change to Francois's answer to be the accepted one

Comment: facing this problem for android os 4, after i migrated codebase from rn 0.59.9 to 0.60.5, can you mention which library causes the crash?