# ReactNative - Android NoSuchKeyException fatal error

Tags: android, react-native, fatal-error

Cannot locate the problem (it happens on clients devices, not in mine), please help.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException: backgroundColor
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue + 109(ReadableNativeMap.java:109)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getValue + 113(ReadableNativeMap.java:113)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getInt + 156(ReadableNativeMap.java:156)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewProps.isLayoutOnly + 252(ViewProps.java:252)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer.isLayoutOnlyAndCollapsable + 445(NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer.java:445)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer.handleCreateView + 94(NativeViewHierarchyOptimizer.java:94)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.handleCreateView + 259(UIImplementation.java:259)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView + 252(UIImplementation.java:252)
   at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView + 465(UIManagerModule.java:465)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 515(Method.java:515)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke + 371(JavaMethodWrapper.java:371)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke + 150(JavaModuleWrapper.java:150)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback + 733(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 95(Handler.java:95)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage + 26(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 136(Looper.java:136)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run + 225(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
   at java.lang.Thread.run + 841(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576030/react-native-android-error-in-com-facebook-react-bridge-nosuchkeyexception

Comment: @AkilaDevinda that question is about lineNumber key, not backgroundColor

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue as in one of my **css** file I'd:

`backgroundColor: null`

and converted to

```
backgroundColor: 'transparent'
```

You can also check if **backgroundColor** is not ***undefined***