# When using Firebase query parameter "in" I get "operator" error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I am running a React Native app that is connected to Firebase and I am trying to replace an "==" in a where clause with an
"in" operator:

Instead of

```
          firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("Post")
              .where("authorID", "==", "John")
```

I transformed it into:

```
           firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("Post")
              .where("authorID", "in", ["John", "Maria"])
```

I receive the error `com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException operator`

I have already installed the library mentioned in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576030/react-native-android-error-in-com-facebook-react-bridge-nosuchkeyexception)

I am using `react-native-firebase` library version `5.6.0` .

What is the source of this error?

Comment: It seems there is an extra semicolon: `firebase.firestore().collection("Post");.where("authorID", "in", ["John", "Maria"])`. Shouldn't it be `firebase.firestore().collection("Post").where("authorID", "in", ["John", "Maria"])`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec that is just a question typo. Sorry.

Comment: I have found this document that would help you. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html

Comment: I've also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576030/react-native-android-error-in-com-facebook-react-bridge-nosuchkeyexception that explains this error.

Comment: @MrTech I have already added that library as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: To move forward, there should be more to the message including the file name and line number. Can you provide this?

Comment: @MrTech as mentioned in the question, it is error com.facebook.react.bridge.NoSuchKeyException operator .

Comment: To get more information do you have crashlytics available? It provides more detailed logs.